# Ruby's PTY gives different results in a method, in a script, and in IRB/Pry

Tags: ruby, pty

I get 2 different outputs (disregarding unimportant stuff):

#### Output 1

```
2.5.0
"Mystery Train\r\n^D\b\b\r\n"
"Mystery Train\r\n^D\b\b\r\n"
```

#### Output 2

```
2.5.0
"Mystery Train\r\n^D\b\b\r\n"
"Mystery Train\r\n^D\b\b\r\n2f1675da1e96a41954149a646cf6fb40\r\n"
```

The code is below, and here are the results the correspond with running it different ways:

Script - output 1
IRB - output 2
Pry - output 2

The question is - **why do I get different outputs between script and repl and between method call and not?**

I've run this on OSX using Ruby v2.5.0 and `md5`, and on Ubuntu with Ruby v2.5.1 and `md5sum` to virtually identical results (any difference are because of md5 vs md5sum's output format).

```
warn RUBY_VERSION # sanity check

MD5 = "md5"
TEXT = "Mystery Train\n\x4"

require 'pty'

def pty!
  master,slave = PTY.open

  pid = spawn(MD5, in: slave, out: slave )
  master.puts TEXT

  begin
    p master.read_nonblock 4096
  rescue Errno::EAGAIN
    IO.select([master])
    retry
  end
ensure
  master.close
  slave.close
end

pty!

puts "----"
# code below is identical but not wrapped in a method


master,slave = PTY.open

pid = spawn(MD5, in: slave, out: slave )
master.puts TEXT

begin
  p master.read_nonblock 4096
rescue Errno::EAGAIN
  IO.select([master])
  retry
end
master.close
slave.close
```

I've tried changing the order of execution, using Process.wait…, using a pipe along with the slave pty but I get the same results. If the difference between the repl and the script was down to the repl using `eval` then why does the method not work in the repl?